# Defining a function using a function typedef in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, typedef

I am implementing a service in Windows.  VisualStudio 2012 has the following function typedef:

```
typedef VOID WINAPI SERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONW (
    DWORD dwNumServicesArgs,
    LPWSTR *lpServiceArgVectors
);
```

There is also a function pointer typedef:

```
typedef VOID (WINAPI *LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONW)(
    DWORD   dwNumServicesArgs,
    LPWSTR  *lpServiceArgVectors
);
```

How do I define a function with this function signature, using the typedef?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need (and cannot) use typedef in a function definition. To make a service  main function, just write:

```
VOID WINAPI SvcMain( DWORD dwNumServicesArgs, LPWSTR *lpServiceArgVectors )
{
    // ...
}
```

`LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONW` is used internally by Windows to call every service start point. Generally, you need function pointer `typedef` to call, and not to define a function.

Answer (score 8):

Quoting the current C++ Standard (C++11):

[dcl.fct]/10

> A typedef of function type may be used to declare a function but shall not be used to define a function (8.4).
>   [Example:
>
> ```
> typedef void F();
> F fv;             // OK: equivalent to void fv();
> F fv { }          // ill-formed
> void fv() { }     // OK: definition of fv
> ```
>
> —end example ]

That is, you can declare but not define the function using that `typedef`. You have to specify the signature explicitly, see Alex Farber's answer.

---

To some extent, you can use the `typedef` to "define" the function, but it involves some template magic. It's a just-for-fun example to show that you can actually use it to define a function.

```
// extra definitions for SSCCE
  typedef unsigned int DWORD;
  typedef wchar_t* LPWSTR;
  #define VOID void
  #define WINAPI

// function ptr
typedef VOID (WINAPI *LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONW)(
    DWORD   dwNumServicesArgs,
    LPWSTR  *lpServiceArgVectors
);

// function typedef
typedef VOID WINAPI SERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONW (
    DWORD dwNumServicesArgs,
    LPWSTR *lpServiceArgVectors
);


template < typename... TT >
struct disassemble_funcptr
{};
template < typename Ret, typename... Args >
struct disassemble_funcptr < Ret(Args...) >
{
    typedef Ret return_type;

    static Ret Func(Args...)
    {
        /* your code here */
    }
};

// using the typedef SERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONW to define the function
LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONW my_func_ptr =
  & disassemble_funcptr < SERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTIONW > :: Func;

int main()
{
    LPWSTR str = nullptr;
    my_func_ptr(42, &str);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With C++11, you can use the the fact that lambdas with empty capture lists are convertible to function pointers to declare and define a function that matches a function typedef in one expression, e.g:

```
using my_function_t = void(*)(int,int);

my_function_t add_function = [](int x, int y) { return x + y; };
```

Answer (score 1):

A function cannot be *defined* <strike>(or declared)</strike> using a `typedef`. It has to be defined in the conventional way. e.g.

```
void foo (type1 t1, type2 t2) // t1 and t2 are objects which can be ... 
{                             // ... visible only in conventional way
  ...
}
```

Function pointer typedef can declare function pointer, which can be assigned with the function's address:

```
typedef void (*PF)(type1, type2);
PF pf = &foo;
```

Comment: If I'm not completely wrong, it can be declared, see my answer.

Comment: As @DyP says, you can declare a function using an appropriate `typedef` (the first example in the question), but you are correct that you cannot define a function using a `typedef` (and DyP is not suggesting that you can define a function either).

Comment: Yes and my compiler agrees with both of you - it can be declared but not defined.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, @Dyp (+1 to the answer), that's correct I have edited the answer. However, can the declaration with a `typedef` completely replace the regular declaration (for example, how about default arguments)?

Answer (score 0):

**This can be accomplished by inverting the attempted approach.**

- ***Define a macro which expands to the desired type***

```
#define defLedClkFunc(name)   void (name)(uint16_t led)
```

- ***Use the macro to define your typedef***

```
typedef defLedClkFunc(tLedClkFunction);
```

- ***Use the macro when declaring the function implementation***

```
//********************************************************
//
// Declaration of first function
//
defLedClkFunc(ledClkEnable)
{
  // Body of first function
} // ledClkEnable()

//********************************************************
//
// Declaration of second function
//
defLedClkFunc(ledClkDisable)
{
  // Body of second function
} // ledClkDisable()

//
// Create an array of pointers to the functions
//
tLedClkFunction *myFuncs[] = {
                             ledClkEnable,
                             ledClkDisable,
                             };
```

Now you have a single-point definition of the function signature, and any changes to the signature propagate through all of the typedefs and function declarations.

I find this incredibly useful for defining sets of functions (e.g. interrupt handlers, message handlers).

In addition, the macro makes it trivial to change ***all** function names if someone decides they should all have some arbitrary prefix and/or suffix.  Just use token pasting as part of the macro definition and paste the desired prefix/suffix around `name`.

You ***do*** need to remember the data type created in order to manipulate pointers to the functions, but even that could be auto-adapted with a trivial amount of additional macro-magery.