# How to consistently wrap many functions with diverse names and argument lists with consistent C++ overloads?

Tags: c++, c++11, preprocessor

I want to create macros which allow me to define wrappers for many functions all at once.  For example:

```
#define WRAPPER2(Type, cxxfunction, ret_type, cfunction, ...) \
    ret_type cxxfunction(__VA_ARGS__) { return cfunction(__VA_ARGS__); }

#define WRAPPER(cxxfunction, ret_type, cfunction, ...) \
    WRAPPER2(uint8_t, cxxfunction, void, cfunction ##_u8, __VA_ARGS__) \
    WRAPPER2(uint16_t, cxxfunction, void, cfunction ##_u16, __VA_ARGS__) \
    WRAPPER2(uint32_t, cxxfunction, void, cfunction ##_u32, __VA_ARGS__)

void c_example_u8(uint8_t*, size_t);
void c_example_u16(uint16_t*, size_t);
void c_example_u32(uint32_t*, size_t);

void c_example2_u8(uint8_t*, uint8_t const*, size_t);
void c_example2_u16(uint16_t*, uint16_t const*, size_t);
void c_example2_u32(uint32_t*, uint32_t const*, size_t);

WRAPPER(example, void, c_example, Type*, size_t);
WRAPPER(example2, void, c_example2, Type*, Type const*, size_t);
// Sometimes wrappers will even use `template<Type>` arguments, too!
```

(as an aside, the trivial `cfunction##suffix` identifier composition is actually [much more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76283035/2417578))

As written above it does not work for two reasons:

1. `__VA_ARGS__` needs to expand to different things based on where it's used -- once with types and argument names, and once with just the argument names.
2. `Type` used within `__VA_ARGS__` needs to be replaced with the first parameter of `WRAPPER2`.

A bit of [preprocessor magic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76394109/2417578) can solve problem 1:

```
#define WRAPPER2(Type, cxxfunction, ret_type, cfunction, ...) \
    ret_type cxxfunction(ARG_PARAMS(__VA_ARGS__)) { return cfunction(ARG_NAMES(__VA_ARGS__)); }
```

Unfortunately references to `Type` are not replaced with the actual type of each instance.  So to solve problem 2 how about a template?

```
#define WRAPPER2(Type, cxxfunction, ret_type, cfunction, ...) \
    template <Type> \
    ret_type cxxfunction(ARG_PARAMS(__VA_ARGS__)) { return cfunction(ARG_NAMES(__VA_ARGS__)); }
```

Nope.  This makes all the implementations use the same instance of `cfunction`, which is supposed to vary by type.  So we'll have to specialise:

```
#define WRAPPER2(type_, cxxfunction, ret_type, cfunction, ...) \
    template <Type> \
    ret_type cxxfunction(ARG_PARAMS(__VA_ARGS__)); \
    template<> ret_type cxxfunction<type_>(ARG_PARAMS(__VA_ARGS__)); { return cfunction(ARG_NAMES(__VA_ARGS__)); }
```

Well, not that because we still have the word `Type` used in the argument list of the specialisation, in a context where it no longer refers to a template argument.

How about a [different approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42486652/2417578)?

```
#define WRAPPER2(type_, cxxfunction, ret_type, cfunction, ...) \
    template <Type> using cfunction##_t = ret_type(__VA_ARGS__); \
    cfunction_t<type_>* const cxxfunction = [](auto... args) { return cfunction(args...); }
```

Unfortunately this introduces a new problem that I can't create overloads of the same function.  Also it needs C++14, not C++11 (curiously, even C++14 blocks use of `constexpr` in the above form, but it's allowed in C++17).

How about a generic variadic template wrapper?  Unfortunately the things I found suffered from type inference troubles when passing, eg., an `int` for a `uint8_t` argument.  In general, if the template infers arguments from the way it's called, these aren't necessarily aligned with the argument list of the function which needs to be called.  And in many approaches, being close enough for a regular function is *not* close enough when it's several layers of template wrapper.

One case of *needing* to be precise about the declared function argument list is when a caller tries to pass a class with an implicit type conversion, but the type cannot be deduced from a variadic template argument.

Writing all this out feels like I've almost rubber-ducked my way to an answer by combining a couple of things I haven't tried together yet, but I'm *so tired* at this stage.  I need help.

Comment: Use templates to do this (overloads of template functions are possible).

Comment: Is there are reason _why_ you are not using templates?

Comment: @TedLyngmo because the implementation for `uint8_t` calls `c_example_u8` and the implementation for `uint16_t` calls `c_example_u16` and templates can't synthesize new symbol names.

Comment: You could have different implementations for `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` if you need too, but why not just call the function `c_example`? You could make it a function template or overload it manually if you want to.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). If your problem is "get a bunch of C pseudo-overloads into type based C++ overloads without a bunch of typing", you might be able to solve it like this: https://godbolt.org/z/ocTeT8nEf

Comment: Just copy and paste it. Going through insane macros doesn't make the code any easier to maintain. If at some point it becomes untenable, which would be a huge failure on the part of the C interface, then do code generation.

Comment: @Artyer that's certainly the requirement in broad terms.  I do actually need to manipulate some of the types on their way through, which is why I included the argument lists in the macros rather than trying to derive them with `decltype`, but I can treat that other ways and I think you've given me enough information to solve this.  The technique for merging the overloads as functors is essential.  Thanks!

Comment: @Artyer Just so you're aware, gcc doesn't seem to care, but Clang starts rejecting that code starting from C++17, because the specialisation isn't specialised enough.

Comment: @sh1 I seem to have run into https://stackoverflow.com/q/51779059 . The reference can be replaced with a pointer pretty easily to fix it: https://godbolt.org/z/YnrMqhKdc

Comment: @Artyer Another observation while messing about; `functor_combiner` doesn't seem to be necessary (the `using` directives don't seem to be necessary).  I get the same callable results with `static constexpr struct : ftor0, ftor1, ftor2 {} superfunctor;`.  Like so: https://godbolt.org/z/4jxb6z6Yc  Is this going to bite me later?

Comment: GCC.  It'll bite me on GCC.  And ICC, which also protests that the object is not initialised, so needs `{}` after the name to make the initialization explicit.